# How to price for global packaging rights

Tags: adobe-photoshop, copyright, illustration, licensing, packaging

I've searched all over Google and couldn't find a suitable answer so I thought I'd go to the source.
How would you go about pricing for global packaging rights on illustrations you create?
Pricing for the actual work carried out and the time spent on putting the illustrations together is not a problem. But when it comes to figuring out how much you should charge for the full rights to reproduce the illustrations on packaging globally is where my problem is. I have no idea where to start with coming up with a figure for that.

It's the first time I've been asked by a client to provide a quote for the rights to my work and just wondered if there was a rule of thumb or a formula to help come up with a ballpark.
Any help anyone could provide would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Whatever you come up with, might not seem right after you get a bit more experience. For that reason, consider a time-limited restriction. You could build-in an option for renewal after a deadline. Thus, your global packaging rights would last for two years, say.